# IMPUTE N.A. BINARY SEX DATA in R

Tags: r, binary, na, missing-data, imputation

I have a dataframe "df_customers" with a binary variable "sex". Of this column, 1.5% are missing, they are NA.
Of the non-missing values, "Male" accounts for 60.81%, and "Female" obviously the rest.

I have assigned these proportions as values males_impute and females_impute:

```
# PROPORTION OF NAs IN VARIABLE SEX

customer_NAs <- nrow(filter(df_customers, is.na(sex)))

# IMPUTATION PROPORTIONS OF MALE / FEMALE ACC. TO COMPLETE VALUES

males_impute <- (nrow(filter(df_customers, sex=="Male")) / 
   ((nrow(df_customers)) - customer_nas) * 100)

females_impute <- (nrow (filter (df_customers, sex=="Female")) / 
   ((nrow(df_customers)) - customer_NAs) * 100)
```

Is there a method of imputation in R for "Male" and "Female" that will impute values into the NAs randomly but according to these proportions? Thanks!

Comment: I know the package **missMDA** works perfectly fine for imputation, but i don't know if it can do what you requiere. Check-out the documentation: https://cran.univ-lyon1.fr/CRAN/web/packages/missMDA/missMDA.pdf

Comment: @MonJeanJean imputation packages are great when you want a model behind your imputation, but for a very simple proportional replacement using an external package seems like overkill and unnecessarily introducing new dependencies.

Comment: Yes ofc, sorry i can't help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure--`dplyr::coalesce` is useful for filling `NA`s, and since your imputation is purely random we can use `runif()` to generate random numbers and assign values:

```
df_customers %>%
  mutate(
    sex = coalesce(sex, ifelse(runif(n()) < females_impute / 100, "Female", "Male"))
  )
```

---

As a side note, as you can see your code converts proportions to percent by including `* 100`. This answer then needs to convert back to proportions with `/ 100`. In general, I'd suggest leaving this as proportions in your code because calculations work better with raw proportions. If you want to display or report percents, use `scales::percent()` to convert, round, and nicely format it. (`scales` is a `ggplot2` dependency, so you probably already have it installed.)

Comment: That's great it worked! Thanks a lot! Could you please clarify why ```n( )``` is left with no arguments?

Comment: Not all functions take arguments. `Sys.Date()` returns the current date. `getwd()` returns the current working directory.  `n()` returns the number of rows in the current data (or group).  (`n()` is a special `dplyr` function that only works inside `dplyr` functions)